# Firebase Realtime Databse DataSnapshot only Read the last value in the child

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm calling `addValueEventListener` inside the button click, but this method only reads the last item in the node. I want to read all the child value in the node What went wrong here?

```
btnorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                SelectedItems si=dataSnapshot1.getValue(SelectedItems.class);
                                si.getItemname();
                                Toast.makeText(MyBookedItems.this, ""+si.getItemname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
        });
```

Comment: please elaborate you question. What exactly you want

Comment: I want to read all the child values ? for answering this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968183/how-to-subtract-two-different-node-child-values-in-firebase-realtime-databse)

Comment: You should try addChildEventListener instead of addValueEventListener

Comment: I just tried, I got same output as before

Comment: If you use addChildEventListener , you don't use  for-loop. Remove for-loop. Try again

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's read all the values but I got the output as a Toast message, because of that I only see the last value)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an array list and put all snapshot data into it, and then you can find the last data of the list with the value you find by subtracting one from the length of the list. Sorry for my bad English :( I have tried to explain in the solution in the code below)

```
    ArrayList<SelectedItems> selectedItems = new ArrayList<SelectedItems>();
for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
 {
     SelectedItems si=dataSnapshot1.getValue(SelectedItems.class);
     selectedItems.add(si);
   }
selectedItems.get(selectedItems.size());
```